# Work out if date is a weekday in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a more succinct way to work out if a date is a weekday in an if statement in t-SQL?

I want something more succinct than below

```
if ((DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @date) = 'Monday' or DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @date) = 'Tuesday' or DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @date) = 'Wednesday' or DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @date) = 'Thursday' or DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @date) = 'Friday'))
    --do something
```

Comment: Check it's not Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: Do you need something that works reliably, no matter what settings are in effect? Because your current example relies on language settings. Other solutions may rely on datefirst settings, etc.

Comment: What about national holidays? (I.e. other non-working days than Saturdays and Sundays.)

Comment: I just need to work out the weekdays not bothered about weekends or public holidays

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UK/US standard `DATEFIRST` (default) settings

Use the `WEEKDAY` function

```
CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(@date) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN @dosomething ELSE 'WEEKEND' END
```

Comment: This only works with particular `DATEFIRST` settings in effect. E.g. `SET DATEFIRST 4` and then running the above for `20150822` reports that it's not a weekend.

Comment: It works with standard (UK/US) `DATEFIRST` settings (7) which i would imagine the User is using as there from NI. Updated my answer to clarify anyway.

Comment: But the point of SO is to be a good Q&A site, working not *just* for the OP and their immediate problem but also future visitors. Do you think it's safe to assume that all future visitors will also be from NI?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to put it in an IF statement for different reasons ill not go into

Comment: @wubblyjuggly - you can take any of these answers using `CASE` and just take the expression between `WHEN` and `THEN` and use that as the logic in your `IF` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the opposite: if it's a weekend day.

```
select case when datename(weekday, getdate()) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 end weedayBoolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Working a bit like previous answers but relying on neither language nor [`datefirst`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) settings:

```
select
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,@date) in (
        DATEPART(weekday,'20150822'), --"Known good" Saturday
        DATEPART(weekday,'20150503') --"Known good" Sunday
    ) THEN 'Weekend'
    ELSE 'Weekday'
    END
```

Comment: If the point of SO is to be a perfect Q&A site, then all cultural definitions of [weekend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend) would be considered. Future visitors might still find that new cultures, Acts of Congress, Microsoft marketing decisions and other intervening occurrences have altered the applicability of both questions and answers. Shall we agree to accept answers that don't meet the [Aaron Betrand Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309179/subtraction-of-two-dates-in-t-sql/19324609#19324609) standards?

Comment: @HABO - I would hope we could, at least, agree that answers that document any assumptions they are based upon are better than answers that will fail for some people and leave them struggling to uncover the issues?