# how to update each row using a counter in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to update each row in the firstName column to display FN1, FN2, FN3 etc.  I know I'm missing a where clause that is causing an update to all the records.  All the firstNames are different so I can't do a simple where condition i.e where firstName = 'adam'.

How can I go about updating all the rows with FN + Counter?

I was made aware I can use a row_number function but was told to use the while loop first for learning purpose.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter = 1

WHILE (@Counter <= (Select COUNT(firstname) FROM CONSTITUENT_TEST))
BEGIN
    UPDATE CONSTITUENT_TEST
    SET firstname ='FN' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter)
    SET @Counter = @Counter  + 1
END
select * from CONSTITUENT_TEST
```

Comment: Though I'll not "bare" with you, you might want to use a [`cursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with a `while` loop _solely_ for educational purposes. A set-based solution is generally preferable.

Comment: Is the intention that `firstname` loses what ever value it had before? So `'Adam'` would be `'FN1'`, not `'Adam1'` or even `'AdamFN1'`?

Comment: Correct.  firstname loses its value. So Adam would be 'FN1'. Each row after with will be FN2, FN3 etc.

Comment: I was told that I did not need to use a cursor(It is slow).  Also, I was told I did not need to use a while loop but instead I could just use a row_number function.  I'm confused.  But I was told to go ahead and complete my rookie code with a while loop before reading up more on row_number function.  All I'm trying to do is write a code to update each row in the firstName column to FN1, FN2, FN3 etc...

Comment: Aside: The default length of a `Char`, `VarChar`, `NChar` or `NVarChar` is one character most of the time. When it is the target type of a `Cast` or `Convert` then it is 30 characters. Best practice: Always specify a length.

Comment: For future reference, SQL questions generally require knowledge of the schema (and often how it is used) to answer. The obvious thing to do in your loop is to base the update on the primary or unique key of the table. And just so you know - this type of loop is simply a more error-prone version of a cursor. If you need a cursor, then use one. But you don't need one at all. Using loops in SQL is (or should be) rare.

Answer (score 1):

If you *had* to do this with a `WHILE` loop, you could use an `UPDATE` with a `TOP (1)` and check that a row was updated in the prior `UPDATE` statement like so:

```sql
DECLARE @Counter int = 0;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 OR @Counter = 0 BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;

    UPDATE TOP(1) dbo.YourTable
    SET Firstname = CONCAT('FN',@Counter)
    WHERE Firstname NOT LIKE 'FN[0-9]%';
END;
GO
```

Honestly though, like mentioned in the comments, I would suggest using a set based solution, it'll it *far more* performant. You can achieve this with an updatable Common Table Expression (CTE) and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Firstname,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --SELECT NULL for arbitrary order. You can use a specific one if you want to
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET Firstname = CONCAT('FN',RN);
```

Comment: The `while` loop may result in duplicate `Firstname` values since it does not guarantee that every row will be updated, e.g. it will skip updating `'FN42'` and `'FN5BY5'`. It will likely result in duplicates if it is run several times with rows being inserted between runs. The OP didn't mention that the names should be unique nor that the query might be executed more than once.

Comment: I mean, if we want to guess *everything* @HABO we might as well assume the OP has bad data too and some has a name like `FN8B74Q Sir Harold of Buttington`... If the OP has such data, or plans to do it more than once, *they* need to us that; I'm going to play the 101 assumptions game. But I don't condone the `WHILE`, and is why I provide the other solution.

Comment: Sorry that you took my comment as a complaint about your answer. I just wanted to point out a couple of assumptions that might affect the OP and others who cut'n'paste the code without understanding what it's doing. I didn't intend to invoke the [Aaron Bertrand Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324609/92546).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variation of what Larnu posted. It uses the primary key (assumed to be the column ID) of your table to iterate through the rows.

```
DECLARE @Counter int = 0;
DECLARE @ID int;

SET @ID = (select min(ID) from dbo.YourTable); // assuming ID is the primary key for your table
IF @ID IS NULL RETURN; // maybe throw an error? Table is empty

WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;

    UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET Firstname = CONCAT('FN', @Counter)
    WHERE ID = @ID; 

    SET @ID = (select min(ID) from dbo.YourTable where ID > @ID); 
END;
GO
```

You could easily convert this into a cursor if you want to explore that option as well. As I wrote earlier - if you need a cursor then just use one. But rarely do you need one.

Comment: Thank you SMOR.  This got my brain ticking and working.  I finally figured out what I was missing and what I need to do.